# Too many input arguments, even with varargin

Tags: matlab, variadic-functions, pca

Unfortunately I am getting a "Too many input arguments." error from performing this call:

```
[varargout{1:nargout}]=pca(varargin{1},'Algorithm','svd','Economy',fEconomy);
```

on the function that has signature as follows:

```
function [coeff, score, latent, tsquared, explained, mu] = pca(x,varargin)
```

I am calling princomp in this way:

```
[pc,score,latent,tsquare] = princomp(data);
```

Any idea of what might be the cause? (the bug appears in *princomp.m* of the *stats* package)

Comment: Can you give more context? Maybe a minimal non-working example?

Comment: Is it possible that it's a function within `pca` that has too many input arguments?

Comment: How are you calling princomp?

Comment: @Molly, I just added the call in the question text

Answer (score 6):

Look at the output of,

```
which -all pca
```

The first item should be something ending in `\toolbox\stats\stats\pca.m`.  My guess is that you have another `pca.m` somewhere on your path.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because you have in the path a similiar function as the matlab built-in function: use this command to clear your path and try again.

```
userpath('clear')
```

note that this command will remove all the libraries you have added into the matlab path.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen for class methods that are defined outside of the classdef file (in a class folder), but that do have their method *signature* defined in the classdef file (see [Methods in Separate Files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/methods-in-separate-files.html)). If the function definition has the varargin argument, but the method signature in the classdef file doesn't, then you'll get this error when you try to pass in arguments.

Comment: It appears that the problem that you're describing could manifest itself in a manner similar to the described question. However, this question is really only about matlab functions (which, frankly, was all I or anyone I knew ever used when I was a heavy matlab user). Perhaps you should create a new question to describe what the class case looks like (MWE) then link back to this answer. (You can accept your own answer)

Comment: I could, but I don't think it's necessary. When I had this issue, I googled almost exactly the title of this question, because I didn't realize it was a class method signature issue. I just saw that my function had varargin as an argument, but was telling me I had too many inputs. I suspect this would be the case for anyone with the issue, because once you realize the problem has to do with class methods, you're practically at the answer.